# MVC log in doen't work

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication

for some reason my MVC project wont let me do the login mechanisem, it won't get back to the httpPost but insted be looping on the origenal loging action. why???
what i've tried is:
        public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View();
        }

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogInInfo li, string returnUrl)
    {
        return View("hi");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LogInInfo li, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (IsValid(li))
        {
            // authetincation successfully
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(li.Name, false);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                return RedirectToAction("About");
            else
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        // failed            
        return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
    }
```